# how to make image draggable in placed in <a-scene> using <a-assets> and <a-image>

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I am trying out augmented reality for web for which i am using aframe-ar.js and aframe.js. I want to make a image draggable which i have placed in `<a-scene>`. I have use `<a-assets>` tag to first register the image and then used `<a-image>` to display the image when the marker is identified in the webcam. The image was displayed successfully but i am not able to make it draggable even after trying many options. My code goes here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Augmented Reality For Web</title>
    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script src="aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <script src="aframe-click-drag-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-click-drag-component"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;'>
    <a-assets>
    <img id="my-image" src="Samplee.jpg"><img>
    </a-assets>
    <a-image id="img_disp"  src="#my-image" rotation="90 180 0" 
    visible="true">
    </a-image>  
    <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
    </a-scene>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't built into A-Frame, but you can use a 3rd party component to get the desired results.

[`aframe-click-drag-component`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-click-drag-component) allows for clicking and dragging entities around on the screen:

Check out [the demo](https://jesstelford.github.io/aframe-click-drag-component/).